# English to Morse code converter, how can I make it more efficient?

Tags: java, hashmap, converters, morse-code

//I'm just a beginner, this is my first program, it's working fine but is there any way I can make it better?

```
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Character alphabet [] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' '};
String morseCode [] = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. ", "--. ", ".... ", ".. ", ".--- ", "-.- ", ".-.. ", "-- ", "-. ", "--- ", ".--. ", "--.- ", ".-. ", "... ", "- ", "..- ", "...- ", ".-- ", "-..- ", "-.-- ", "--.. ", "| "};

//putting alphabets and morsecode in HashMap
Map<Character, String> morseCodes = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++)
{
    morseCodes.put(alphabet[i], morseCode[i]);
}

//Took user input and converted it into LowerCase Character Array
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = sc.nextLine();
char[] translate = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

//Translating user input(translate[]) using for loop
for(int j=0; j<input.length(); j++){
    System.out.print(morseCodes.get(translate[j]));
}
}
}
```

Comment: You could indent it properly.

Comment: This is not really a specific programming problem.

Comment: I believe this type of questions are more welcomed at [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange

Comment: The enclosing parentheses in `(input.toLowerCase())` are not needed just remove them

Comment: Fine enough. Abbreviate like `Map<Character, String> morseCodes = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for code review, not a specific question.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry it was my first post so I didn't know how to do it properly. Thanks for letting me know, next time I'll make sure of these things. :)

@khelwood

Comment: @Lino Hi, Thanks man, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @JoopEggen Hi, Thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code was good but I think this solution is more efficient

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

      String morseCode [] = {".- ", "-... ", "-.-. ", "-.. ", ". ", "..-. ", "--. ", ".... ", ".. ", ".--- ", "-.- ", ".-.. ", "-- ", "-. ", "--- ", ".--. ", "--.- ", ".-. ", "... ", "- ", "..- ", "...- ", ".-- ", "-..- ", "-.-- ", "--.. ", "| "};

       //Took user input and converted it into LowerCase Character Array
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String input = sc.nextLine();
       char[] translate = (input.toLowerCase()).toCharArray();

       //Translating user input(translate[]) using for loop
       for (int j = 0; j < translate.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(morseCode[translate[j] - (int)'a']);
       }
}
}
```

I removed the hashmap, this is efficient in some case but here no need this data structure.

Explaination by @Shirkam :

"By doing it, your are converting the ASCII value of the letter 'a' to an int (97, I think). Doing that allows you to transform ASCII value of translate[j] to a 0 scale value, instead starting in 97. This allows you to directly use the array as they all start in 0. In resume, you are moving ASCII values to the left to be able to use an array directly."

Comment: Hi, you are amazing, I just don't understand the main thing.
can you make me understand how will this line execute?

morseCode[translate[j] - (int)'a']

Comment: @TosifKhan By doing it, your are converting the ASCII value of the letter 'a' to an int (97, I think). Doing that allows you to transform ASCII value of `translate[j]` to a 0 scale value, instead starting in 97. This allows you to directly use the array as they all start in 0. In resume, you are moving ASCII values to the left to be able to use an array directly.

Comment: Also, @Cylexx keep in mind that your answer is totaly functional, because `','` and `'|'` arent after lowercase chars. Infact, `','`is 44 in the ASCII table and `'|'` is 124, so they will require some special treatment.

Comment: @Shirkam I agree, I'll add your comment my answer with your name